# I am having some problem with adding Tailwind to my existing react app with vite. Can someone tell what is the problem with my code

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

Git Repo - https://github.com/rbaliwal00/academia-1.git

Followed proper steps for adding tailwind to my existing project but it is still not working. Most of the examples are regarding just downloading the example react app with vite but there is no proper way to add tailwind to an existing project. Can anyone help me with adding tailwind to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you followed all the 6 steps described in the Tailwind [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite)?

To me, it looks like at least the `postcss.config.cjs` is missing. So try to run `npx tailwindcss init -p` to properly initialize tailwind and afterwards, it should work.